# How do I install a Wordpress theme on localhost where WP is asking for the FTP credentials

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to install a WordPress theme on my localhost. The theme is GloriaFood. This is the message I'm getting:

```
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.
```

I'm being asked for the hostname and ftp credentials.

Comment: Not all questions on StackOverflow are strictly about programming, however, this is rather a simple Google search.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to copy the theme in the required folder. You don’t need to use FTP for local files.

Here is a good article on how to do it:
https://zemez.io/support/wordpress/how-to/install-wordpress-theme-local-server-based-wamp/